# Connect SQL Server 2008 to Outlook Calendar?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, calendar, outlook

I’ve been asked to integrate our holiday Calendar which is stored in an SQL Database with an outlook calendar, so that all holidays show in outlook etc. I’ve googled this a lot and haven’t really found a way that I can do this without purchasing 3rd party software.

Has anyone any experience in this and if so could you help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Exchange, as the mail server for Outlook, then you can link this to a SQL Server instance.

Below is an example using a SQL statement, you can also do this via the UI in SSMS.

Example

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'exchange', 
    'Exchange OLE DB provider', 
    'exoledb.DataSource.1',
    'file:\\.\backofficestorage\localhost\public folders'
```

Once linked [OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312(v=sql.100).aspx) can be used to read from Exchange.

Example

```
SELECT 
    convert(nvarchar(30),"urn:schemas:contacts:sn") AS LastName,
    Convert(nvarchar(30),"urn:schemas:contacts:givenname")  AS FirstName,
    Convert(nvarchar(30), "urn:schemas:contacts:o") AS Company,
    Convert(nvarchar(50), "urn:schemas:contacts:email1") AS Email,
    "urn:schemas:contacts:bday" AS BirthDay
FROM
    OpenQuery
        (
            Exchange, 
            'SELECT 
                "urn:schemas:contact:sn", 
                "urn:schema:contacts:givenname", 
                "urn:schemas:contacts:o",
                "urn:schemas:contacts:email1",
                "urn:schemas:contacts:bday"
            FROM 
                ''.\contacts'''
        )
;
```

Examples taken from [full Instructions, on Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191461(v=sql.100).aspx).

For more on Exchange see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dn820100.aspx).